# Unity3D ViewModel Z depth buffer fix floating point

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, shader, depth-buffer, zbuffer

Do anyone know how to fix floating point issue with Meshes and Skinned Meshes ?

Rust have found a solution for this issue and Garry explained here : http://garry.tv/2014/04/07/unity-viewmodels/

***I want to know how works the rust way, not the unity3d way.***

Do anyone know how it works, how solve that issue ? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: **Seriously ? Anybody are able to help me with this ?**

Answer (score 0):

Have your player GameObject on a different rendering layer. An objects "Layer"
 is noted at the top of the inspector next to "Tag" and below "Name".  What the article is saying is to make a separate layer for just your model and have a a single camera render only that layer.  Only one camera should render the model layer and only the model layer. Then overlay the model-layer camera on top of the main camera. (For information on overlaying cameras, try youtube)

Comment: Iknow that but the model do not have shadows. and it not fix the floating point issue